# Find the Next Different Occurrence

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

In my project, I often need to check a `QByteArray` for the next byte that is different. So in an array with 999 zeros and 1 non-zero byte, I would like to find the index of the first byte that isn't zero.

Normally, I would loop through each byte until I find one that isn't zero. But since indexOf just finds the next occurrence of a given value, is there a similar function that does the exact opposite of indexOf?

Performance times are the reason I'm doing this. I do a ton of these loops just to find the first indifferent byte. Any way to do the same faster without just looping through each byte?

Comment: I doubt that any variant of `indexOf` will be faster than simple linear lookup.

Comment: Hmmm. Is indexOf essentially just a loop as well?

Comment: For 1 byte search it is. Anyway, there's no built-in function to get the index of the first non-matching byte. You'll have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a uniform array of same bytes and only some are different you may get a big increase in performance by converting your array pointer in (qint64*) or (qint32*) depending on your machine and step eight or four times faster trough the array.

This is done by `qint64 * foo = (qint64*)byteArray.data();`

This way 1024 bytes to check would melt down to 128 qint64 comparisons or 256 qint32 comparisons to find the set of bytes to examine closer to find the actual differing byte.

Example:

0000 0000 0000 0000 0100

Differing byte at position 18

If you use qint32 you need four steps (depending on how you initiate the search) to find the qint32 being different from the other because it's value is not 0.

This or a similar approach might help you to speed up your search.

Comment: Ooooo! Very smart! I'll try this out soon and let you know how it goes. I like that idea!